# JavaScript OOP scope of visibilty

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop

My code looks like this:

```
function A() {
    this.AFunction = function() {
        var b = new B();
        b.BFunction();
    }
}

function B() {
    this.BFunction = function() {
         // some code
         $.ajax({ url: url
             success: BSuccess,
             // and so on
         })
    }

    this.BSuccess = function() {
         // some code
         this.anotherBFunc();
    }

    this.anotherBFunc = function() {
         // some code
    }
}

a = new A();
a.AFunction();
```

And it fails on the calling anotherBFunc. Could please some one help me understand why does it happed?

Comment: some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Use `this.BSuccess.bind(this)`: http://jsfiddle.net/fRUJn/2/

Answer (score 1):

To maintain scope you can use [jQuery's proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
success: $.proxy(this.BSuccess,this),
```

or with modern day browsers you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
success: this.BSuccess.bind(this),
```

Comment: By "modern day", you mean "any browser anyone is actually using" http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind :)

Comment: People still use IE8 I am afraid and it is not modern.

Comment: Only estimated at 10% of the global internet, there comes a point... http://theie8countdown.com/

Comment: Global !== Company's User Base.

Comment: Okay, you win: Internet Explorer 8 has a great future, and is worth paying money to support indefinitely. The cost:benefit analysis heavily favors not only targeting the browser exclusively, but we should all go buy Microsoft stock on the strength of that software alone. :P